# Getting the sine of an angle as a double in c++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

For my app, as I get wrong results caused by rounding errors (for instance, the distance calculated between two points separated by 1853m at the surface of the earth is 0!), I need to compute sine and cosine with a double precision. Unfortunately, I can't find any suitable functions in the NDK.

How could I get more accurate results?

The formula I use is `60*1852*toDegrees(acos(sin(toRadians(lat1))*sin(toRadians(lat2))+cos(toRadians(lat1))*cos(toRadians(lat2))*cos(toRadians(long2-long1))))`

with lat1=45.7729721; lat2=45.792984; long1=2.96383333; long2=2.96895313

Comment: First thing you should do is to break up that long line into several computations, so that you can find out where the rounding issues occur and address those calculations.

Comment: Hmm. do you use `double` for your variables? It should calculate `sin`/`cos` in double precision already.

Comment: Already tried to break up the long expression... Compared to a scientific calculator, differences for each sin or cos appear at the fifth ou sixth digit after the decimal point.

Comment: @geza Thanks Geza. With a few casts to "double", I get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Tackling this problem by trying to get higher precision seems like a bad idea to me. Your problem is horribly-conditioned and not very tractable with floating point numbers.

Let's take a look at the important expression (omitting the conversions):

```
acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(long2-long1))
```

For your input data, `lat1` and `lat2` are extremely close to one another. Further, the difference between `long2` and `long1` is very small, so its cosine will be *extremely* close to one.

Given this, the expression inside the `acos` is almost exactly this identity:

```
sin(x)*sin(x) + cos(x)*cos(x) = 1
```

Hoping to take the `acos` from this expression will yield exactly the result you observed, since floating point numbers won't deal with this well (you have a lot of precision around zero but not around other integers).

You should look to use a different formula altogether. I am a bit rusty on my clever trigonometric identities, but if you have the geometry at hand from which you derived this, it shouldn't be hard to obtain a different definition that involves less catastrophic loss of precision near `1`.

---

Ok, armed with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities, Consider this:

```
sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) = 0.5 (cos(lat1 - lat2) - cos(lat1 + lat2)) =: a
cos(lat1)*cos(lat2) = 0.5 (cos(lat1 - lat2) + cos(lat1 + lat2)) =: b
cos(long2-long1) =: c
```

The expression then becomes `acos(a + b * c)`, or

```
  0.5 (1 + c) cos(lat1 - lat2) - 0.5 (1 - c) cos(lat1 + lat2)
```

The terms that have dangerous cancellation here are `(1-c)` and `cos(lat1 - lat2)` (at least for your given inputs). For the former, you could try looking for polynomial approximations that calculate `1 - cos(x)` accurately for `x` close to `0`. Eliminating loss of precision in the latter is more difficult (but also not as crucial for your given inputs).

Comment: While your reasoning can be right (I haven't read it fully), the numbers OP use should produce a good result in double precision.

Comment: @geza The last `cos` alone calculates only seven significant `double` digits. Windows calc gives me `0,99999999600763048017366864048184`, `double` has ~16 significant digits around `1.0`. And that's a term that gets folded into a value to `acos` that is for all intents and purposes `1` already.

Comment: @geza The `acos` argument is `0,99999993706236262324711684728014`. Without the `cos(long2-long1)` factor, the argument would be `cos(lat1-lat2)` or `0,99999993900399614839805988293966`. The difference between the two is the `2e-9` (makes sense, each almost-square is about 0.5).

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. The true value of OP's example is: ~2258.8379895734, while using doubles I get: 2258.83798862704953. It has a pretty good value.

Comment: @geza I guess you're right, the `acos` gives you back some of the significant digits the `cos` lost (as long as you don't lose them all, like `float` does).

Comment: Ah, now I may understand your reasoning. Yep, the result doesn't have 16 correct significant digits, but has more than 8, which can be good for the OP. But, of course, with other inputs, this can be much worse. So, it is worth transforming the original formula to something else, which has much better (and guaranteed) precision. It maybe worth to put another question to ask this (with the floating-point tag).

Comment: Why do you say my problem is "not very tractable with floating point numbers"? The same expression written in Java and using double numbers gives a very satisfying result.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks for the time you spent trying to answer me, but why changing the formula to adapt it to the numeric example given ("eliminating loss of precision in the latter is more difficult (but also not crucial for your given inputs)")?